# How to calculate the f-score using MultiClassMetrics in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, rdd

As I see in the pyspark documentation, the `fmeasure()` function takes two arguments which are `label` and `beta`:

```
fMeasure(label=None, beta=None)
```

What is beta here?

I'm using a very simple data set like this which is in RDD:
(It's in dataframe but I convert it to RDD)

```
+----------+-----+
|prediction|label|
+----------+-----+
|         1|    1|
|         1|    1|
|         0|    1|
|         0|    0|
|         1|    0|
|         1|    0|
|         0|    0|
|         0|    0|
|         1|    1|
|         1|    1|
+----------+-----+
```

And when I run this command:

```
multi_metrics = MulticlassMetrics(rdd)
print 'fMeasure: ', multi_metrics.fMeasure(1)
```

I get this error:

```
print 'fMeasure: ', multi_metrics.fMeasure(1)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py", line 259, in fMeasure
    return self.call("fMeasure", label)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 146, in call
    return callJavaFunc(self._sc, getattr(self._java_model, name), *a)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
    return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 312, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name, value))
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o154.fMeasure. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method fMeasure([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is beta here?

Spark's `MulticlassMetrics` implements $F_{\beta}$-measure, which coincides with the traditional F-measure if you put $\beta$ = 1. The $\beta$ parameter allows to [control relative contributions of precision vs recall in F-measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score).

*About the error*: if you look at the implementation, it actually expects a `Double`. Here is the pyspark wrapper for [fMeasure](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/python/pyspark/mllib/evaluation.py#L255) method and here is the actual [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/evaluation/MulticlassMetrics.scala#L123) (in Scala).

So you should be good calling it like this, for instance:

```
multi_metrics = MulticlassMetrics(rdd)
print 'fMeasure: ', multi_metrics.fMeasure(1.0,1.0)
```